# ORDER BY MIN date

Tags: postgresql

I need to fetch the number of employees per month, having a first work in a selected period. And I have to display only the month when the employee appears for the first time. My request works fine, but I need to order the result by date. Here is my request:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(sub.minStartDate,'mm/YYYY') as date,
       COUNT(DISTINCT sub.id) AS nombre
FROM (
    SELECT MIN(sw.start_date) as minStartDate,
    e.id
    FROM employee e
         INNER JOIN social_work sw ON e.id = sw.employee_id
        GROUP BY e.id
        HAVING MIN(sw.start_date) BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2022-12-31'
    ) sub
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date
```

And the result:

```
date    | nombre
--------------
04/2021 | 2
05/2020 | 1
```

Excepted output:

```
date    | nombre
--------------
05/2020 | 1
04/2021 | 2
```

I've tried to put sub.minStartDate in the ORDER BY clause but then I also have to put it in GROUP BY clause, what gives me this output :

```
date    | nombre
--------------
05/2020 | 1
04/2021 | 1
04/2021 | 1
```

And it's not what I want.

Comment: Assuming `sub.minStartDate` is actually a  timestamp, do `GROUP BY sub.minStartDate::date  ORDER BY sub.minStartDate::date`.  Otherwise specify what type `sub.minStartDate` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're ordering by `date`, which is the result of the `TO_CHAR()` function. The `TO_CHAR()` function returns a text, so your `ORDER BY` clause results in an alphanumeric sort.

Since you don't want to `ORDER BY sub.minStartDate`, you could try changing your format to put the least significant variable of the date (in this case, the month) to the right: `TO_CHAR(sub.minStartDate, 'YYYY/mm')`.

If you can't change your format either, then you'll probably have to resort to grouping and ordering by `minStartDate`:

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(sub.minStartDate,'mm/YYYY') AS date,
    TO_CHAR(sub.minStartDate,'YYYY/mm') AS sortingDate,
    COUNT(DISTINCT sub.id) AS nombre
FROM
    -- omitted for simplicity
GROUP BY date, sortingDate
ORDER BY sortingDate
```